# Android Select Count() Query does not work

Tags: java, android, select, count

I am working on my Android mobile application.
now this code is working fine

```
    ArrayList<adapter_car> carlist = new ArrayList<>();
    ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
    query = "SELECT * FROM [GatheringareaDB].[dbo].[cars] WHERE car_id_ga_in_cars = '"+v1id+"'";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

the problem is that I can't change the * to anything else (not the name of the columns, not count(*), etc..).

what I want is to count some columns like so

```
SELECT([car_sog_car]) , Count([car_sog_car]) 
FROM [GatheringareaDB].[dbo].[cars]
WHERE car_id_ga_in_cars = v1id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off.  If you just want to get the count of records across the entire table, given your restrictions, then use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM [GatheringareaDB].[dbo].[cars]
WHERE car_id_ga_in_cars = v1id;
```

For your Android code, you should use a prepared statement here:

```
Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM [GatheringareaDB].[dbo].[cars] WHERE car_id_ga_in_cars = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.createStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, v1id);
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
if (res.next()) {
    int count = res.getInt("cnt");
}
```